# SSIS Cannot retrieve the column code page info from the OLE DB provider

Tags: ssis

I'm working on SSIS Package which has oracle backend.

On OLE Command Task, I get the warning below:

> "Cannot retrieve the column code page info from the OLE DB
>   provider..."

I am aware that there is way to set AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage to true on **OLEDB DataSource**. But I've not seen how to fix on **OLE Command Task**.

Could someone please help? Also what are the consequence of not fixing this issue?

Comment: First thing is that the values assigned by default are correct. Second , make sure the datatypes are the same on source and destination. Last save your project, close your project> open the project and run.. It should work just fine...

Answer (score 39):

On the DataFlow task, open the Advanced Editor, select the Component Properties tab and in the Custom Properties section set the AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage to True

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me. To answer the second part of your question, there should be no consequence of not resolving this error. The code page is the character set of non-unicode strings. Changing this setting basically tells SSIS to assume that the code page 1252 (default for SQL server). And if you are pulling from 2 sources in the same language, you should be fine. More details here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc1a61f2-1ab8-4ed3-b85c-db6481800b50/error-importing-data-from-oracle-database-to-an-sql-database?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I had this problem with VS 2017 ent against an oracle database on an ssis preview.   The setting of code page to true made the error mentioned above go away.  But on preview I was still getting some kind of error with "cannot find message text number 0x80040e51" message.  Since it was Preview (probably just the GUI developer complaining) I ignored that message and continued to code the package.   The package ran on Azure with no errors so the 2nd message did not occur at run time.  The performance was very good compared to an ADO.Net task doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

After ages of scratching my head i found the solution

On the OLE DB Source ensure you have delay validation set to true

I set the default code page to false

and had the code page as 1252

I have tried this both with 32 bit and 64 bit.